# images upload with angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

i got at small problem with an images upload in angular.

This code is working fine it send to the PHP with out eny trobels, i can se the the post REQUEST is there an array of data, the problem is when i try to print_r($_FILES); php say theres is and empty array.

```
    socialCtrl.directive('upload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
            var formdata = (window.FormData) ? new FormData() : false;

            $(".upload").bind("change", function (evt) {
                var file = this.files[0];

                if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                    if ( window.FileReader ) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                            $(".preview").find("img").attr("src", e.target.result);
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }
                    if (formdata) formdata.append("file", file);
                }   

                if (formdata) {
                     $http({
                       method: 'POST',
                       url: 'php/imagesuploader.php',
                       data: formdata,
                       cache:false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                   }).success(function(result) {
                        console.log(result)
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't POST a file like this, you have to either submit this as form data (as multipart form data) or transform the request (as shown in [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm) blogpost).

Simple example of how to post form data is shown below.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
})
.success(function(){
})
.error(function(){
});
```

Comment: i just want to on change the file should be uploadet. so html form it´s only an input name="file" adn type="file" /> there is nothing else so that code you have there will not work to my case

Comment: I think this should work, you just need to add the transformRequest and headers to your $http POST request.